# How to create scheduled website parse and notification on it?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm setting up my website+android app link. On my website I can check notifications. I want to check my website for a new posts, and if it exists, make notification on it.

I think I need to make service. How I can make it scheduled for, for example, every 30 minutes. How I can do that?